# Apps not updating in some devices from iTunes Store

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

I have updated my app with another version to iTunes Store.But the app does not get updated in few devices. Those devices got the last update may be from iCloud. Did i miss something in iTunes or app setting ?

Answer (score 0):

No , If you have done successfully upload and release the next version then every device can able to download the new updated app from app store.
Delete the old app and download new one from app store. Definitely you will get new one. (You can check the version number in appstore while downloading)

**Further:**

Else you should give **force update** functionality in your app.So every app user have to forcefully download the new version of your app.

This may also helps you:

https://www.lifewire.com/iphone-cant-update-apps-fix-4057706

https://www.technobezz.com/iphone-ipad-wont-download-update-apps/